# Mostrar y ocultar elemento

Tags: html, botón

tengo este código para mostrar y ocultar un texto y me funciona, el problema es que por defecto el texto me aparece mostrado y me gustaría que estuviera oculto por defecto y se mostrase cuando le doy al botón, he intentado solucionarlo pero no encuentro la solución.

```js
function mostrarOcultar(id){
var elemento = document.getElementById(id);
if(!elemento) {
return true;
}
if (elemento.style.display == "none") {
elemento.style.display = "block"
} else {
elemento.style.display = "none"
};
return true;
};
```

```html
    
<div id="ocultable">Soy un texto ocultable.</div>

<button onclick="return mostrarOcultar('ocultable')" type="button">Mostrar/Ocultar</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creo que con aplicar un pequeño estilo sería suficiente, el estilo sería `display:none` y se puede aplicar a prácticamente cualquier etiqueta html, te dejo ejemplo de como quedaría en tu caso.

```js
function mostrarOcultar(id){
    var elemento = document.getElementById(id);
    if(!elemento) {
        return true;
    }
    if (elemento.style.display == "none") {
        elemento.style.display = "block"
    } else {
        elemento.style.display = "none"
    };
    return true;
};
```

```html
<div id="ocultable" style="display:none">Soy un texto ocultable.</div>

<button onclick="return mostrarOcultar('ocultable')" type="button">Mostrar/Ocultar</button>
```